# I only have permission to add files to download and document folder

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, permissions

All folders I add files to except for download and documents  gives me a message saying I don't have permission.

I tried manually changing the permissions chmod and it still gives me trouble.

Can anybody tell my why my computer won't let me add files to most of my folders? I use Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: Is the machine yours? What does `ls -l` show the permissions to be?

Comment: my home folder permission is drwxr-xr-x and my desktop permission is drwxr-xr-x+

Comment: Never mind I fixed it.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you posted the problem as an answer

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Write your answer in the box below, then click post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `chmod`ing each individual folder I instead changed the permission for the entire Home folder and this fixed the problem.